# jquery dialog takes a while to open

Tags: jquery, performance, dialog

Currently we have a jquery dialog which contains 4 tables. Each hasa number of checkboxes in it:

- First box has about 10 checkboxes
- Second about 300 (one per country)
- Third and forth have about 100 each

When I click on the button to open the dialog it can take a while
IE7 = 10seconds
IE6 = 15+ seconds

Even chrome takes 2 seconds to simply open a dialog (a noticeable delay).

Is jquery just not able to process the dialog open quickly when its has a dialog with alot of DOM objects?

P.S. The dialog has already been initialized on page load, so I would assume the dialog open would be near instant.

Comment: Is the content added first and than you open the dialog or are you adding the content (the checkboxes etc.) afther you opened the dialog? The last case could be slower maybe. Of course it is also all depending on your machine.

Comment: You need to show us some code so we can see what you are doing

Comment: the content is already added to the box before we call the open. its a bit tricky to paste the code but may give it a go shortly!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try to open the dialog box and then append the content. sometimes this considerably improves the performance.

```
$('#dialog ').dialog('open');
$('#dialog ').html(yourContent);
```

Also try familiarising yourself with jQuery performance rules as there is such thing as writing bad slow jQuery:

http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

And finally sometimes when the content of the modal box are heavy setting the draggable to false also can improve the performance of the box. so if you don't need the draggable try:

```
draggable: false
```